# HSTS or ATS equivalent for Android?

Tags: java, android, security, hsts

My iOS apps are secured with ATS to enforce security.
Websites are using HSTS.
What is the equivalent technology for Android?

Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android introduced similar functionality in API level 23. You can do this in the `network_security_config.xml` file. This is the example from the [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/preview/features/security-config.html#CleartextTrafficPermitted):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">secure.example.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Make sure you including your `network_security_config.xml` file in your application's manifest as specified at the beginning of the documentation, otherwise the file will be ignored.

> Is there any way to specify that all traffic to all domain should be encrypted?

Yes. Update the [`base-config`](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#base-config) element and set the `cleartextTrafficPermitted` attribute to `false`.

```xml
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that I don't immediately see a way to enforce TLS 1.2 in the configuration / application manifest.

Comment: This only specify TLS to `secure.example.com` (and its subdomains), right? Is there any way to specify that *all* traffic to *all* domain should be encrypted?

Comment: @FranklinYu sorry it took me... months... to respond, but yes, see updated answer.